# Can the intersection of int[] array and BitSet be faster?

Tags: java, arrays, intersection, bitset

In Java, I have a BitSet bigger in size than an array (`100000 > 2000`). Array contains positive integers from range `[1; 100000]`. I want to intersect given array and bitset. Obviously intersection will be of size less than the size of an array, so I want to store it as an array. My code below:

```
BitSet b = new BitSet(100000);
int[] a = new int[2000];
// fill in b with some bits and a with positive integers in range from [1; 100000]

// intersect array a and bitset b and keep result in separate array
int[] intersection = new int[a.length];
int c = 0, i = 0, j = b.nextSetBit(0);
while (i < a.length && j >= 0) {
    if (a[i] < j) i++;
    else if (a[i] > j) j = b.nextSetBit(j+1);
    else {
        intersection[c] = j;
        i++; j = b.nextSetBit(j+1); c++;
    }
}

// usually intersection is less than a array in size so cut it
int[] zip = new int[c];
System.arraycopy(intersection, 0, zip, 0, c);
```

Is it possible to get faster in time code than the presented above one?

**EDIT** array `a` is sorted, for example `a = { 2, 115, 116, 2034, 26748 }`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *intersection* here? I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish well enough to comment on whether it could be done faster.  Intersection usually means "elements of both", but you're trying to perform intersection on different types of values that are already disjoint, so you must have had some kind of definition in mind that is non-standard.

Comment: This code seems to depend on array `a` being sorted. Is that intended?

Comment: @Gian One way of thinking of a BitSet is as a representation of a set of integers, containing the integers for which the corresponding bit is set. I think the OP wants the intersection between that set of integers and the integers that appear in the int[].

Comment: @Patricia Yes, array `a` is indeed sorted, sorry forgot to mention it. And yes, Patricia, you got it right, well done.

Comment: Patricia's answer is almost certainly optimal, in this case, being `O(n)` if you assume `BitSet.get` is `O(1)` (which I think it is).  You could possibly tweak the termination condition to detect when you've iterated past all the values that could be included in the intersection, but that's really just adjusting `n` down by a small constant factor.

Comment: @Gian Agree, as I understood, by `n` you mean `a.length`. Not very clear about detection, but I guess you are right. Even if this constant is small, I do care about micro-optimization because this intersection operation happens billions of times in my code.

Comment: If that's the case, wouldn't you be better off not spending the time sorting your input array and instead using two BitSets?  Computing the intersection of two BitSets should be as simple as a bitwise `and`, and that should be amenable to vectorization (either explicitly or automatically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely simpler, and I think may be faster, because it only accesses those elements of `b` whose index is in `a`. It does not scan the whole of `b` looking for the next set bit.

```
  public static int[] intersect(BitSet b, int[] a){
    int[] rawResult = new int[a.length];
    int c = 0;
    for(int i : a){
      if(b.get(i)){
        rawResult[c] = i;
        c++;
      }
    }
    int[] result = new int[c];
    System.arraycopy(rawResult, 0, result, 0, c);
    return result;
  }
```